# Undefined variation of configurable products

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, simple-product

I have created a configurable product that has 5 variations. Configuration works great and simple boxes are made just fine.
Now if I want to add a value option of one of attributes I get new products showing undefined.

Let's say I have product variation color and when I created thd configurable product originally i had 3 colors, red, blue and orange.  and let's say my base sku for the configurable products is BASE.

So when I create the configurable product, magento creates simple products with name BASE-blue, BASE-red, and BASE-orange.

Now let's say I decided to add a new variation value for variation color, and its purple, so I go to the attribute, add purple, save, go to the configurable product, edit the configuration, add purple to the variable configuration, then once I finish the configuration dialog, magento says i'm making new simple product Undefined-purple, instead of BASE-purple.  How can this issue be fixed ?

Comment: Try to edit the variation from the base product ?

Comment: That's how you edit the variation, from the base product @FranckGarnier

Comment: have you already found a solution for that problem?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140178)